# Value of $\ \sum_{r=1}^{n} (-1)^{r-1}(1+ \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} + \ ...\ +\dfrac{1}{r}) {n \choose r}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

My approach:

$(1){n \choose 1} - (1+ \dfrac{1}{2}){n \choose 2} + (1+\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3}){n \choose 3} - (1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}){n \choose 4} \ ...$

Grouping the terms:

$1[{n \choose 1}-{n \choose 2}+{n \choose 3}...] - \dfrac{1}{2}[{n \choose 2}-{n \choose 3}+{n \choose 4}...] + \dfrac{1}{3}[{n \choose 3}-{n \choose 4}+{n \choose 5}...] \ ...$

However, I can't seem to proceed any further. My school material offers a hint regarding this problem, saying to 'use integration' without any other context, but I don't see how integration can be used in the first place since the terms associated with each binomial coefficient is itself a sum of harmonic series. Any hints or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer:

> It simplifies to $\dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: You may use $$
1 + \frac{1}{2} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{r} =  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^r {( - 1)^k \frac{1}{k}\binom{r}{k}} 
$$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) and the inverse formula for the binomial transform (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform#Definition).

Comment: Hint: what is this integral? $\int _0 ^1\frac{1-x^{r+1}}{1-x}dx$? Try to use it.

Comment: This problem has been asked several times, check [Approach0's search result](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5C%20%5Csum_%7Br%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20(-1)%5E%7Br-1%7D(1%2B%20%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%20%2B%20%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%20%2B%20%5C%20...%5C%20%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Br%7D)%20%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20r%7D%24&p=1)